# UPDATE mutliple rows but not if the value already exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers (
    PhoneNumber varchar(15) PRIMARY KEY
    DateTimeAdded datetimeoffset
)
```

The `PhoneNumber` column contains E.164-formatted phone numbers.

There's a problem in that a few numbers are missing their country prefix, so I need to run an `UPDATE` query that adds the "`+1`" or "`+44`" or other prefixes (for this exercise, I know they all need "`+1`" as their prefix (so don't worry about "`+44`" and other country-codes).

I thought about this:

```
UPDATE PhoneNumbers
SET PhoneNumber = '1' + PhoneNumber
WHERE
    LEN( PhoneNumber ) = 10
    AND
    PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '1%'
```

This SQL works fine in principle, except that some of the numbers were correctly entered at a subsequent point so the SQL fails with a primary-key conflict.

What is an `UPDATE` query I could run that checks to see if the resultant value already exists before performing the actual update?

I thought about this:

```
UPDATE PhoneNumbers
SET PhoneNumber = '1' + PhoneNumber
WHERE
    LEN( PhoneNumber ) = 10
    AND
    PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '1%'
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM PhoneNumbers As P2 WHERE P2.PhoneNumber = '1' + Number )
```

But the subquery doesn't work as-intended. I tried `UPDATE PhoneNumbers As P1` and referencing `P1` in the subquery, but SQL Server says that's bad syntax.

Comment: What "bad syntax" error do you get?

Comment: Do you just want to ignore those values that you cannot update? I'd have thought that you'd probably want to delete them (possibly after updating dependent rows elsewhere to reference the correct value) and if you did that before the update, there wouldn't be a problem - or have I misinterpreted this cleanup exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your correlated subquery, you forgot to correlate the PhoneNumber with the outer table; so your subquery should be something like (untested):

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM PhoneNumbers As P2 WHERE P2.PhoneNumber = '1' + PhoneNumbers.PhoneNumber)
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. I thought that wouldn't work because it would do a join on itself (i.e. think the `PhoneNumbers` in the `WHERE` was not the table in the `UPDATE`)

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve your goal like this:-

```
UPDATE p1
SET PhoneNumber = '1' + PhoneNumber
from PhoneNumbers p1
left join PhoneNumbers p2 on p1.PhoneNumber='1'+P2.PhoneNumbers
WHERE
    and p2.phonenumber is null
    and LEN( PhoneNumber ) = 10
    AND
    PhoneNumber NOT LIKE '1%'
```